# Show each data in different boxes using FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I am working on fpdf, I want to created boxes and show each data from database in differnt boxes. Like if I have 2 boxes with different XY dimension so I want to show value 1 in first box and value 2 in second box, But issue is when I used my code it is showing both value 1 and 2 in both boxes. My code is

```
$w = array(82,95); //for XY dimension
for($i=0;$i<2;$i++)
{
  $reusult1 = $GLOBALS['conn']->query($sql2);
  $queryresult=mysqli_num_rows($reusult1);
  $this->Rect($w[$i], 47.5, 13, 9);

  $this->SetXY($w[$i] , 47.5);
  $this->SetFont( "Arial", "", 9);

  while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($reusult1)){

    $this->Cell(4,4,$rows['position'],1,0,'C');
 }
}
```

in `$rows['position']` have values `1` and `2`.

Comment: What does `$result1` contain after  your query?

Comment: mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 20 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 5 [type] => 0 )

Comment: I see no `position` in that object yet that is what you are trying to output in the `foreach` loop. Regardless, you need to move the positioning of the rectangle to inside of your `foreach` loop from what I can tell using the information you've provided.

Comment: I have edit the code,in $rows i have position filed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic was looping through both of the XY positions twice AND through the results twice. I don't have your data to test this with but it should solve your problem.

```
$reusult1 = $GLOBALS['conn']->query($sql2);
$w        = array(82,95); //for XY dimension
for($i=0; $i < 2; $i++) {

  $this->Rect($w[$i], 47.5, 13, 9);
  $this->SetXY($w[$i] , 47.5);
  $this->SetFont( "Arial", "", 9);
  $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($reusult1);
  $this->Cell(4,4,$data['position'],1,0,'C');

}  // end of for loop
```